# Syntax error in Perl open

Tags: perl, syntax-error, conditional-statements

I have the following conditional code as part of my script and I keep getting a syntax error for only the last `open` call. Suggestions?

```
if ($contig_string =~ /($pattern)/) {
        print "$ERR_number \n";
        print "Found forward pattern.\n";
        print "Pattern found is: $1 \n";
        $position = index($contig_string,$1);
        print "Index returned: $position \n";
        $substr_forward = substr($contig_string, $position, -2000);
        print "$substr_forward \n";  
        open (REPORT, ">>", spacer_contigs) or die "Could not open";
        print REPORT ">$ERR_number \n";
        print REPORT "$substr_forward \n";
        }
elsif ($contig_string =~ /($pattern_reverse)/) {
        print "$ERR_number \n";
        print "Found reverse pattern.\n";
        print "Pattern found is: $1 \n";
        $position_reverse = index($contig_string,$1);
        print "Index returned: $position_reverse \n";
        $substr_reverse = substr($contig_string, $position_reverse, 2000);
        print "$substr_reverse \n";
        open (REPORT, ">>", spacer_contigs) or die "Could not open";
        print REPORT ">$ERR_number \n" or die "Could not append";
        print REPORT "$substr_reverse \n";

        }
elsif ($contig_string !~ /$pattern_forward/) {
        print "$ERR_number \n";
        print "Did not find pattern. \n"
        open (NOMATCH, ">>", no_match) or die "Could not open"; # SYNTAX ERROR
        print NOMATCH ">$ERR_number \n" or die "Could not append";      

        }
```

Comment: Just to be to clear, are the `**` for emphasis / bold? Markdown styling isn't available within code blocks. It'd be better to add a comment within the snippet near the line or shorten the snippet to what's really needed. Also, if you can include the message given by the error within your post, that can usually be helpful.

Comment: You are missing a semicolon on a previous line

Comment: You also have your `die` messages mixed up. `>>` is append, and `>` is overwrite.

Comment: When you are checking the status of an `open` call you should *always* include the value of the built-in variable `$!` in the `die` string to say *why* the open failed

Answer (score 7):

You're missing a semicolon on the `print` before the `open` that is causing trouble.

Also, there's seldom a need to output blanks before newlines.  You have numerous strings such as:

```
print "Did not find pattern. \n"   # This is where the semicolon should be
```

that would be better written as:

```
print "Did not find pattern.\n";
```